# What is normal symfony 3 load time in development?

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I have optimized performance by this documentation page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html#optimizing-all-the-files-used-by-symfony

except parts "Caching the Autoloader with APC" and Use Bootstrap Files¶ 
because when calling line

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

I got an error.

But page still loads at best about 2.5 seconds even if application does nothing, just outputs small hardcoded text.

I am running php built in server like this:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and version is 5.6

I know with php 7 it should be faster, but before php 7 people still used to code with php 5.6. Were they really coding and waiting 2.5 seconds for each page reload? And if application does some heavier work it then would take even more.

My machine is running on windows 7, 8 GB ram, Intel B960 processor.

Can I do something to increase load time more? I think its a waste of time to wait 2.5 seconds for each small fix because it adds up over time. I want the app to be lightning fast.

Comment: yeah, I remember waiting 4 to 5 seconds for my page to load and I think you can't do nothing about it because in dev environment, there's no caching. After every change, all the files are recompiled ...

Comment: this is weird. It feels like productivity killer. Or need to buy highend end computer for development :/

Answer (score -2):

"Normal Symfony Loadtime" clearly depends on your machine. I've also noticed some high loading times in dev and localhost, whereas in dev on a server (a mid level one) I'm under 300ms per page (and even quite big ones...)
The only fix for me was to develop on a server and abandon localhost.